# Tensorflow Model SSD Mobilenet Detection Threshold Value Edit

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection

I am trying to train an SSD_MobileNet V1 on a custom dataset to detect beef cattle on the farm. I have followed sentdex [tutorials](https://pythonprogramming.net/introduction-use-tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial/) to train the model. It's working right now. However, in the output image, it draws boxes only around the objects with a detection confidence value higher than 50%. No detected object on the output image got lower than 50% detection confidence. I am trying to set the threshold value to 0.3.

To do so I have edited the ssd_mobilenet_v1_pets.config file from -

```
argmax_matcher {
    matched_threshold: 0.5
    unmatched_threshold: 0.5
    ignore_thresholds: false
    negatives_lower_than_unmatched: true
    force_match_for_each_row: true
  }
```

to

```
argmax_matcher {
    matched_threshold: 0.3
    unmatched_threshold: 0.3
    ignore_thresholds: false
    negatives_lower_than_unmatched: true
    force_match_for_each_row: true
  }
```

Then exported the inference graph and used that graph. 
However, nothing has changed in the output, every detected object got higher than 50% confidence. Is there any simple way of changing the threshold value?